# Cannot find Column when Filtering data

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview, runtime-error

when filtering the datagridview the application gives me a runtime error and gives an additional information saying "Cannot find column [p_name]" can't seem to find the problem, hoping someone could help me figure it out, im using Sqlite for my database

here's my code:

```
  Dim DV As New DataView(dt)
    DV.RowFilter = "[p_name] LIKE '" & nSearchbox.Text & "%' AND [t_date] LIKE '" & dSearchbox.Text & "%'"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
```

and here's an image of my database:
[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDVNv.png)

Comment: What is the SQL used to build `dt`?

Comment: I used Sqlite for my Database

Comment: Yes, I got that.  I am asking what the SQL statement is that you used to fill `dt`.  As an aside, I think you are asking for trouble storing everything as text.

Comment: dt as datatable sir

Comment: I know that too.  One more time: what is the SQL Statement you used to Fill the datatable named `dt`?

Comment: "select * from rsdcpatienttbl"

Comment: `String.Format()` would be a safer way to build the query, but it sounds like the DB the app is looking at is different than you think.  Make sure you are loading from the correct path.

Comment: im sure that it's loading the correct path cause all other functions of my app is working well with the Database except for the search function, and one of my form's search function does not give me any error, but when i tried to input a name to search on it, the data on the datagridview disappears

Comment: Well, I doubt that .NET is lying to you.  We cant see *that* datatable being initialized so we cant know what it contains.  If it is not a local object, it could map to any table or no table. Debug your code: Set a breakpoint on the last line shown; when it stops, create a QuickWatch from `dt`; then drill into the columns collection to see if there is a `p_name` column

Comment: Have you tried removing the brackets around p_name; `p_name`. So your filter would look like this `"p_name LIKE '%" & nSearchbox.Text & "%' AND [t_date] LIKE '%" & dSearchbox.Text & "%'"`